# CakePHP paginate and order by

Tags: php, cakephp

It feels like I've tried everything so I now come to you.

I am trying to order my data but it isn't going so well, kinda new to Cake.

This is my code:

```
$this->set('threads', $this->paginate('Thread', array(
        'Thread.hidden' => 0,
        'Thread.forum_category_id' => $id,
        'order' => array(
            'Thread.created' => 'desc'
        )
    )));
```

It generates an SQL error and this is the last and interesting part:

```
AND `Thread`.`forum_category_id` = 12 AND order = ('desc') ORDER BY `Thread`.`created` ASC LIMIT 25
```

How can I fix this? The field created obviously exists in the database. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$this->set('threads', $this->paginate('Thread', array(
        'Thread.hidden' => 0,
        'Thread.forum_category_id' => $id
    ),
    array(
        'Thread.created' => 'desc'
    )
));
```

I'm not a Cake master, just a guess.

EDIT. Yes, thats right. Cake [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering) excerpt:

Control which fields used for ordering
...
`$this->paginate('Post', array(), array('title', 'slug'));`

So order is the third argument.

Comment: the query runs, but it doesn't order it :/

Comment: @cubsink can you look at new generated SQL?

Comment: accepted your answer since it was correct and you were first :)

Comment: It's little bit wrong answer. Third parameter is `whitelist` so you can specify only couple of fields that can be ordered thru named param `sort` in your pagination helper. But actual sorting param still needs to be set in options array (second param) or in $this->pagination['Model']['order']

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass in the `conditions` key when using multiple filters (i.e. order, limit...). If you *just* specify conditions, you can pass it as second parameter directly.

This should do it:

```
$this->set('threads', $this->paginate('Thread', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Thread.hidden' => 0,
            'Thread.forum_category_id' => $id
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Thread.created' => 'desc'
        )
    )));
```

or perhaps a little clearer:

```
$this->paginate['order'] = array('Thread.created' => 'desc');
$this->paginate['conditions'] = array('Thread.hidden' => 0, ...);
$this->paginate['limit'] = 10;
$this->set('threads', $this->paginate());
```

if you get an error, add `public $paginate;` to the top of your controller.

Comment: Just realized that public paginate was already set at the top with an order statement. Stirred myself blind there for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$all_threads = $this->Threads->find('all', 
            array(
                'order' => 'Threads.created'
            )
        );
        $saida = $this->paginate($all_threads,[
            'conditions' => ['Threads.hidden' => 0]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to take note of in paginate with order. For Cake 3.x, you need :

1) Ensure you have included the fields in 'sortWhitelist'

```
$this->paginate = [

        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'hidden', 'forum_category_id', 
        ],


    ];
```

2) for 'order', if you put it under $this->paginate, you will not be able to sort that field in the view. So it is better to put the 'order' in the query (sadly this wasn't stated in the docs)

```
$query = $this->Thread->find()
->where( ['Thread.hidden' => 0, 'Thread.forum_category_id' => $id, ] )
->order( ['Thread.created' => 'desc'] );

$this->set('threads', $this->paginate($query)
```