# Pagination filter and order

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I need to filter the pager with a DESC order date, I've tried ways but still not work for me, any idea friends?

```
public function admin_index(){
    $this->layout = "admin_default";
    $conditions = array('status'=>1);
    $filter = array();
    if(!empty($this->request->query)){
        $search = basicsLix::removeAcutes('%'.$this->request['url']['search'].'%');
        $filter = $this->request->query;
        $conditions += array('OR' => array(
                    basicsLix::removeSpecialCharacter('purchaser_name')=>$search),
                    'order'=>array( 'payment_date' => 'asc'));
    }
    $purchases = $this->paginate('Purchase', $conditions);
    $this->set(compact('purchases', 'filter'));
}
```

Error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order = ('asc') LIMIT 20' at line 1
```

SQL Query: SELECT `Purchase`.`id`, `Purchase`.`track_id`, `Purchase`.`purchase_order`, `Purchase`.`purchaser_name`, `Purchase`.`purchaser_email`, `Purchase`.`amount`, `Purchase`.`status`, `Purchase`.`dispatched`, `Purchase`.`method`, `Purchase`.`payment_date`, `Purchase`.`hash`, `Purchase`.`created`, `Purchase`.`modified` FROM `resultados_tagid`.`purchases` AS `Purchase` WHERE `status` = 1 AND CONVERT( CAST( UPPER(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(purchaser_name, ',',''), '.',''), '-',''))) AS BINARY) USING utf8) LIKE '%%' AND order = ('asc') LIMIT 20

Comment: $conditions += array('OR' => array(
      basicsLix::removeSpecialCharacter('purchaser_name')=>$search),
      'order'=>array( 'payment_date' => 'asc'));

Comment: throws me the following error

Comment: seems like you haven't even done a basic search... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808573/cakephp-paginate-and-order-by

Comment: https://github.com/CakeDC/search and query strings are the correct approach on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
if(!empty($this->request->query)){
    $search = basicsLix::removeAcutes('%'.$this->request['url']['search'].'%');
    $filter = $this->request->query;
    $conditions += array('OR' => array(
                basicsLix::removeSpecialCharacter('purchaser_name')=>$search)),
    $conditions['order']=array( 'payment_date' => 'asc');
}
```