# Paginate do not sort DESC

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.5

I can't display Agreements with agreement_number less than 7 and order it by agreement_number DESC.

I have read [Pagination CakePHP Cook Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) and can't find where my code is wrong. It display only less than 7, but always ASC. I have found similar question here, [that works],([CakePHP paginate and order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808573/cakephp-paginate-and-order-by)) and do not know why. Agreement.agreement_number is int(4).

```
        $this->Agreement->recursive = 0;
        $agreements = $this->Paginator->paginate('Agreement', array(
            'Agreement.agreement_number <' => '7'
                ), array(
                'Agreement.agreement_number' => 'desc'
            )
        );
        $this->set('agreements', $agreements);
    }
```

Exact cake version is 2.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... Where did you read that that was the correct syntax?

The [paginate](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-PaginatorComponent.html#_paginate) function's third parameter is for sorting (and I mean, within the table... with those down and up arrows).

> List of allowed fields for ordering. This allows you to prevent
>   ordering on non-indexed, or undesirable columns.

You have the exact link used for documentation of the API, but you don't seem to be following it (like, [from here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup))

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'Agreement' => array(
        'order' => array('Agreement.agreement_number' => 'desc')
    )
);

$agreements = $this->Paginator->paginate('Agreement', array(
        'Agreement.agreement_number <' => '7'));
```